# C# Alchemy API: Extract Dates?

Tags: c#, date, nlp, extract, alchemy

I just realized there's no explicit statement in their website that their API, AlchemyAPI can extract dates or various date formats from a website or from given text? Has anyone attempted this and is it possible?

For example:

> 14th of February 2014
>
> 2014/02/14
>
> February, September, December,..
>
> 12th, 14th, 2nd,..
>
> 4th Decade, 7th decade,..
>
> 40th century, 3rd century,..

It's weird how they haven't addressed this issue. Is it possible?